# 3 outcomes: one ordinal regression or two logistic regressions?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordered-logit

Imagine, for example, I am fitting a model with the following data:

```
Dependent variable: disease
0 = no disease (100 cases)
1 = mild disease (300 cases)
2 = advanced disease (100 cases)

Explanatory variables:
x1+x2+x3
```

Please correct me if I am wrong: the proportionals odds assumption maybe does not holds there. Anyway, I could do one ordinal regression or two logistic regressions (if I consider 0 = no disease, 1 = mild/advanced disease and 0 = no/mild disease, 1 = advanced disease). In a sense, you can put the cutoff somewhat arbitrarily: in this case, the advanced disease is "the more serious form" of the mild disease. Keep in mind that both approaches could be equally informative in the clinical sense of the term (and a logistic regression could be easier to understand).

**Which one is the overall best approach? One ordinal regression or two logistic regressions?**

(I use R)

Comment: I don't understand why you think you can't use ordinal regression. The *ordinal* package has a function *nominal_test* to test for the proportional odds assumption.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395433/test-proportional-odds-assumption-with-2-random-variables-r-ordinal-logistic and I will study the issue. Do you have any suggestion (maybe a personal opinion) about the main question?

Comment: I would want to use one model. Ordinal regression makes sense to me, unless I'm missing something .

Comment: How about using multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Multinomial logistic regression is a good advice, do you think that it is appropriate (in the broadest sense of the term) even if my dependent variable is ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Combining several comments and adding some of my thoughts.

Unless there is some reason to use multiple models, I would go with one model. Ordinal logistic regression is the place to start. In R, you can check the proportional odds assumption using `nominal_test`.  Something like:

```
install.packages("ordinal")
library(ordinal)

m1 <- clm(disease ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
nominal_test(m1)
```

If you find violations then one option is multinomial logistic, but there is also the partial proportional odds model, in case the violations are all around one variable.